# Detecting X11 window resize towards top/left

Tags: c, x11, xlib

I'm working on a mapping application and I'm trying to get resizing in X11 working the way I'd like.  Conceptually, I'd like my window to be a viewport onto some real-valued space where my data lives.  When you resize the window, the size of your view onto this real-valued world should change accordingly.

What this means is that when resizing the window, rather than shrinking/stretching the data, more or less of the underlying window becomes visible.  It's easy to handle the case when the window is resized by growing/shrinking on the bottom/right, but I'd like to handle the case when it's resized on the top/left as well.

This is trickier, because a top/left resize also moves the window's origin as well as it's dimensions.  I need to detect the change in the origin so that I can compensate to keep my data centered as the window is resized.

Is there a robust way to get the absolute coordinates of a window in X11?  The coordinates that X11 reports directly through ConfigureNotify and XWinAttributes are dodgy due to window manager reparenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xlib use [XTranslateCoordinates](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XTranslateCoordinates.html) to translate the coordinate (0,0) in your viewport window into coordinates of the root window. This also covers the case of a stacking window manager messing with your window position.

Comment: I tried this using the coordinates in the ConfigureNotify event relative to my parent, but it didn't seem to work.  Is that not the right way?

Comment: BTW: I'm going to sleep now, so I'll only update my answer in a few hours.

Comment: The XTranslateCoordinates with 0,0 relative to the current window, rather than my parent seems to be doing the trick.  There's a bit of a judder going between full screen and back though, but I think it's unrelated.

Comment: @gct: That's exactly the use I was suggesting. With "viewport windows" I intentioned you use the window you call "current window", which is where you show your map.